# EKEvent/EKEventStore and timezones

Tags: ios

I'm adding an event to the calendar and the start date is: 2012-03-22 22:56:30 +0000

However when I look at the entry in the calendar app its time is 3:56PM.

So obviously something to do with timezones, but after looking at the documentation for EKEvent and some googling I'm not the wiser as to how to deal with this.

Answer (score -1):

EKEvents date are stored with GMT+0. But Calendar app display date with your timezone local setting.

So I suppose you're in a GMT-7 time zone because 22:56 - 7 hours = 15:56 = 3:56 PM

The best way to add you're date with your local timezone is by using NSDateComponents:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:2012];
[comps setMonth:3];
[comps setDay:22];
[comps setHour:22];
[comps setMinute:56];
[comps setSecond:30];
NSDate* myDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```

You can use only year, month and day if you want (hours, minutes and seconds will be 0)

Comment: "EKEvents date are stored with GMT+0" This does not seem to be the case as I am getting "John F. Kennedy’s Birthday 2016-05-29 21:59:59 +0000"

Comment: How do you display this date?